Formula to work out distance required between anode and cathode in electrostatic precipitation of smoke particles
I'm having trouble working out the following problem.
I wish to create a basic electrostatic precipitator setup for removing particulates from the chimney of a wood burner.
I understand that there is an optimum distance between the electrodes for best efficiency, but I don't have the (financial) means to test this for myself at present, and would like to get as close as possible to the correct setup using basic off-the-shelf high voltage generators, prior to ordering them.
This will be a simple cylindrical setup with an electrode suspended in the centre of a tubular chimney (a metal tube, insulated on the outside).
I have seen someone (on a youtube video) using a 31mm cylinder with 29kV and that this was effective, and then using a 27mm cylinder with 21kV which was equally effective (relative to the gas flow).
However, I wish to have a much higher gas flow at roughly the same pressure and so the cylinder I require is closer to, say, 200mm in diameter (can be larger if necessary). The distance between the electrodes therefore being approx 100mm (or slightly less, using two positive wires spaced apart in the center of the cylinder, with the cylinder connected to ground).
My question, then, is; Is there a standard equation to work out the voltage required for a given air gap?
The available voltage of off-the-shelf DC high-voltage generators are:
50kV, 400kV, 500kV, 1000kV. So really I'm trying to work out the opposite of what I've said above, i.e., what diameter cylinder (approximately) do I require for each of the above voltages? It doesn't really matter if the chimney is wider than required for the gas flow from the burner, so if I knew the required diameter (air gap) for the 1000kV and 500kV then I could build my design to suit those voltages, within reason.
I hope this makes sense. I know it's not the most well-written question. As you can see, my knowledge is limited.
Ozone generation is not a problem for me, as the chimney and electrodes will be outdoors. All I'm trying to achieve is near-zero smoke output from a chimney in a bunker in an area where I don't wish the smoke to give away the location of that bunker.
{edit} the only other consideration for me is current draw, as all of my power in the bunker is (12VDC) generated from hydro and wind turbines, and so is finite. It appears that a 20kV electrostatic generator draws in the region of 200ma whereas a 500kV would require around 1A, hence I would like to go with the smallest possible ideally, rather than just getting the big boy and making the cylinder wider until it stops sparking, and potentially wasting power.
Thanks very much in advance.
P.S As an afterthought, might I be better off using two meshed plates mounted horizontally within a fully insulated cylinder, and then varying the (vertical) distance between those two charged plates within the height of the tube?
Also, should it be required, the rather vague video I'm referring to is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARSQWTzWago
